# route 53 aws sdk, how to specify n/a region

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I tried passing n/a as region but i gives me error, since on the route 53 settings it is set to n/a

> AWS HTTP error: Client error: 403 IncompleteSignature (client): Credential must have exactly 5 slash-delimited elements

```
$client = Route53Client::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'test1',
    'region'=>'n/a',
    'version' => 'latest'
));
```

region is required, if I remove it gives me required error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wondered why on earth you would think the region should be `n/a`.

Oh. That's how it's shown in the documentation for [Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#r53_region).

That seems incorrect.  It could be that "n/a" actually means any valid region would work, but I would suggest that based on [the example request shown in the API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/requests-rest-overview.html), the region value they are expecting to see is actually `us-east-1`.

Comment: I use us-west-2 on aws ec2, and tried using it on route53 didnt work.

Comment: So... us-east-1, then?

Comment: yes, it worked on us-east-1, maybe its the default? havent read anything about that being default though.

Comment: [AWS Signature Version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) uses a rolling, derived signing key that is built from several pieces of info, including the current date, the specific AWS service, and the region. The services that don't have region-specific API endpoints (Route 53 and IAM, for example) still have to be logically in a specific region for the authentication mechanism to work.  The standard configuration in those cases seems to always be us-east-1, the "original" AWS region.